# Merging Multiple Pandas DataFrames - Some with Shared Unique IDs, Some with Shared Columns

Tags: python, join, pandas, merge, dataframe

Okay, relatively new to *pandas* and Python, so apologies if my question is extremely obvious. Have gone over all of the *pandas* docs on merge, join, and concatenate, read through all of the similar questions on Stackoverflow and Scriptscoop, and have watched hours of *pandas* tutorials on YouTube. But have yet to figure out how to do what I want to do, which seems like it would be relatively easy in *pandas*.

Basically I have a DataFrame for each type of positive bacteria result (E. coli, S. aureus, etc.). Within the DataFrame there is a unique ID (Order) that associates to a patient, as well as a result, date, and ward name. A patient can be positive for just one type of bacteria, or for multiple types, so some of the order numbers between DataFrames overlap, and some only show up once.

For example:

```
    Order  Test_EC  Results_EC     Date     Ward Name
0   K70201  E. coli  MODERATE   2014-01-02    North
1   K70277  E. coli  MODERATE   2014-01-02    North
2   K70205  E. coli  FEW        2014-01-02    West
3   K70818  E. coli  MODERATE   2014-01-03    South
4   K70202  E. coli  FEW        2014-01-03    West
5   K80070  E. coli  RARE       2014-01-03    North
6   K80666  E. coli  FEW        2014-01-03    East

    Order   Test_SA  Results_SA    Date     Ward Name
0   K80766  S.aureus MANY       2014-01-01    West
1   K70201  S.aureus MANY       2014-01-02    North
2   K70277  S.aureus MANY       2014-01-02    North
3   K70205  S.aureus FEW        2014-01-02    West
4   K90107  S.aureus FEW        2014-01-06    North
```

I would like to create a master database based on the order number of a  patient, with an associated column for each positive test and result, as well as the date and ward name. If a patient is positive for one test and negative for another, then a NaN fill would be fine. If two order numbers from different DataFrames match, then they will by definition already have the same date and ward name, so basically the test and results columns will be the only new information.

**In short, I want to maintain all of the information contained in each table, while having all of the associated data for each order number show up in a single row.**

I'm hoping to get something that looks like this:

```
    Order   Test_EC Results_EC  Test_SA Results_SA     Date  Ward Name
0   K70201  E. coli MODERATE    S.aureus MANY      2014-01-02 North
1   K70277  E. coli MODERATE    S.aureus MANY      2014-01-02 North
2   K70205  E. coli FEW         S.aureus FEW       2014-01-02 West
3   K70818  E. coli MODERATE    NaN      NaN       2014-01-03 South
4   K70202  E. coli FEW         NaN      NaN       2014-01-03 West
5   K80070  E. coli RARE        NaN      NaN       2014-01-03 North
6   K80666  E. coli FEW         NaN      NaN       2014-01-03 East
7   K80766  NaN     NaN         S.aureus MANY      2014-01-01 West
8   K90107  NaN     NaN         S.aureus FEW       2014-01-06 North
```

As you can see the resulting DataFrame is three rows shorter, because there were three patients with both an E. coli and S. aureus infection. There are no duplicate values in the order column, yet all of the information has been conserved.

I also want to keep building up such a database by doing the same thing about twenty more times with different bacteria. The actual dataset is about 100,000 unique order numbers.

This post would be too long if I went through all the various combinations of join, merge, and concat functions I've tried, and why they didn't work. I know I'm missing something obvious. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want an 'outer' merge?

```
In [154]: df1
Out[154]: 
    Order  Test_EC Results_EC        Date Ward Name
0  K70201  E. coli   MODERATE  2014-01-02     North
1  K70277  E. coli   MODERATE  2014-01-02     North
2  K70205  E. coli        FEW  2014-01-02      West
3  K70818  E. coli   MODERATE  2014-01-03     South
4  K70202  E. coli        FEW  2014-01-03      West
5  K80070  E. coli       RARE  2014-01-03     North
6  K80666  E. coli        FEW  2014-01-03      East

In [155]: df2
Out[155]: 
    Order   Test_SA Results_SA        Date Ward Name
0  K80766  S.aureus       MANY  2014-01-01      West
1  K70201  S.aureus       MANY  2014-01-02     North
2  K70277  S.aureus       MANY  2014-01-02     North
3  K70205  S.aureus        FEW  2014-01-02      West
4  K90107  S.aureus        FEW  2014-01-06     North

In [156]: df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
Out[156]: 
    Order  Test_EC Results_EC        Date Ward Name   Test_SA Results_SA
0  K70201  E. coli   MODERATE  2014-01-02     North  S.aureus       MANY
1  K70277  E. coli   MODERATE  2014-01-02     North  S.aureus       MANY
2  K70205  E. coli        FEW  2014-01-02      West  S.aureus        FEW
3  K70818  E. coli   MODERATE  2014-01-03     South       NaN        NaN
4  K70202  E. coli        FEW  2014-01-03      West       NaN        NaN
5  K80070  E. coli       RARE  2014-01-03     North       NaN        NaN
6  K80666  E. coli        FEW  2014-01-03      East       NaN        NaN
7  K80766      NaN        NaN  2014-01-01      West  S.aureus       MANY
8  K90107      NaN        NaN  2014-01-06     North  S.aureus        FEW
```

Comment: Hmm. Yes! df1.merge(df2, on=['Order', 'Date', 'Ward Name'], how='outer') seems to work perfectly. Not sure why I was having so much trouble. Thanks for the help!